# How to retrieve data from object tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I created object table using SQL Developer:

```sql
CREATE TYPE PRODUCT  AS  OBJECT(
name        varchar2(40),
category    varchar2(30),
price       varchar2(10));

CREATE  TABLE  S_PRODUCTS  OF PRODUCT;

SELECT VALUE(e) from S_PRODUCTS e;
```

Also, inserted several values into that table. But when I am trying to retrieve this object table as a whole, I a getting weird results (see image in the attachments). As far as I understood, the first part, before the dot is my db username.

[image: query results showing nine rows each containing [DB_231RDM023.PRODUCT]]

I tried to recreate the object table and restart Oracle SQL Developer, but I am always getting the same results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see the columns then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM s_products;
```

or

```sql
SELECT name, category, price FROM s_products;
```

If you want to get the object for each row then use your query:

```sql
SELECT VALUE(e) from S_PRODUCTS e;
```

However, your SQL Developer client application is not configured to display object so it is just displaying the identifier for the object. If you want to see the contents of the object then:

- click on the pencil icon for the cell;
- double-click on the cell; or
- Follow the [ThatJeffSmith's instructions](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2017/01/oracle-sql-developer-display-structured-value-in-grid/) and check the "Display Struct in Grid" option in the preferences under "Datebase > Advanced".

Comment: Thank you! I changed the settings to display struct in grid and it worked perfectly well.